# How to startActivity from service that has android:singleUser and permission INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, multi-user

I'm looking to expand my app to handle Guest Mode, introduced in Android L. I found that if I create a service with android:singleUser in AndroidManifest, with permission INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS, and I'm a system app by installing it in /system/priv-app, then my service is running even as I switch user. But my app needs to interact with the user, by being able to launch an activity, show a toast or notification. All of those things seems to not be possible. Is there a particular flag I need to set when I call startActivity so that it will launch a new activity from my service?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it. Basically have a singleton Service, which is a service with the android:singleUser="true" and with INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS and have the APK installed in /system/priv-app. Then have it broadcastAsUser to all users. You'll need to use reflection to access methods in UserManager. Then have a receiver instance which will receive the broadcast in the guest user's space, and then have the receiver startActivity.

Comment: how was the APK installed into /system/priv-app ?

Answer (score 0):

There are several internal apis (comments as @hide) like Context.startActivityAsUser, NotificationManager.notifyAsUser to support it, but it needs build from source also with platform signature.